# openshift perl module loading

Tags: perl, openshift

I read this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1039356) but I can't figure out how can I use my module in a perl application on the opeshift platform.

This is my module in ./libs/MyModuleA12H.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(test);

package MyModuleA12H;

sub test {
    return 'content...';
}

1;
```

and here my ./index.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n';

print '<html><head><title>HI</title></head><body>';
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use lib dirname($0) . '/libs';
require MyModuleA12H;

print '<div>';
print MyModuleA12H::test();
print '</div>';

print '</body></html>';
```

locally it works but if I commit and reload I get a file not found.

**EDIT**

Looks like a permission issue or something. If I comment all the "use" part index.pl cannot be found.

**EDIT 2**

I made a little mess with the single quotes in

```
print 'Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n';
```

that should be ", now it works, thanks to Borodin for the suggestions I'm applying those changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `use MyModuleA12H` instead of `require MyModuleA12H`, as `require` won't call the module's `import` method

And your `package` statement is too late, so you are importing `Exporter::import` into `main` instead of `MyModuleA12H`

This is how it should look

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package MyModuleA12H;

use Exporter qw( import );

our @EXPORT_OK = qw( test );

sub test {
    'content...';
}

1;
```